# Visual Studio 2022 upgrade

Tags: dllimport, visual-studio-2022, reusability

I required few steps.

1. I have project which is 2019
2. Now i want to use the same dll to upgrade my visual studio 2022 called as version of VS
3. In this case i need to take of Remote debugging dll as well.
4. In my case i have two machine were one is virtual machine and local machine.

Given a try and notice i could see C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional i could all files gets created properly when i copy binaries from old vs 2017, but i could not see much folder IDE with its setup in 2022.

Please let me know how do i finish this upgrading

Comment: VS2022 moved to 64-bit, so it is now installed under c:\Program Files\ instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\.

Comment: Yes it was helpfull, thanls